# extract text from Jenkins console output and store it into a csv file using sed in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have the similar lines of text spread across my Jenkins Console out put:

```
NumberOfTestCases of tier1 in https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git are 4
```

I wanted to extract the following into 3 columns:

| TIER | URL | NumberOfTestCases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tier1 | https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git | 4 |

I have the following code which is extracting only the URl and NumberofTestCases. I wanted to get the first column values as well included in my SED command.

```
wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText -O ${WORKSPACE}/SomeFile.txt


sed -n 's/.*\(https.*git\)\ are\ \([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/\1,\2/p' SomeFilex.Txt
```

Comment: `s/^.* of \([^ ]*\) in .*\(http.../\1,\2,\3/p` ?

Comment: possibly easier with awk: `awk '/^NumberOfTestCases/{print $3,$5,$7}'` or somesuch

Comment: @jhnc both the solutions are not working. Second one is returing empty output.  Where as the firs tone is returning this error:  sed -n 's/^.* of \([^ ]*\) in .*\(http.../\1,\2,\3/p' Autopilot_testcases.txt > testcases.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: Unmatched ( or \(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/NumberOfTestCases/s/[^ ]* ([^ ]* ){2}([^ ]*) [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*([0-9]+)/\2\t\3\t\4/p;1i TIER\tURL\tNumberOfTestCases' somefile.txt
TIER    URL     NumberOfTestCases
tier1   https://****:****@bess-bitbucket.bearingpoint.com/scm/bnktst/stat-autopilot-testcases.git       4
```

Comment: the code is not working. As the ConsoleOutput consists several other text lines as well. I have shared complete log file in the question.

Comment: @ManojKumar You should provide a relevant sample from the start rather than assuming the format will be known. You can try this for the new sample `sed -En '/NumberOfTestCases/s/[^ ]* ([^ ]* ){2}([^ ]*) [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*([0-9]+)/\2\t\3\t\4/p;1i TIER\tURL\tNumberOfTestCases' somefile.txt`